# Database persistence without an SQL server

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm seeking a solution that would allow persistence without requiring an SQL server to be installed on the host and could be bundled along with a desktop application. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: What do you mean by a separate service ?  
jdbc works fine.

Comment: By separate service I meant that a database server needs to be installed on the host beforehand. I'll reformulate my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use an embeddable database written in Java like [Java DB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/) (Sun's supported distribution of Apache Derby), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), or [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) (by the creator of HSQLDB). H2 has my preference performance wise and features wise (some comparisons [here](http://www.justingordon.org/2008/10/in-memory-dbs-for-tdd-h2-versus-hsqldb.html), [here](http://3rdstage.blogspot.com/2009/03/comparion-of-hsqldb-h2-sqlite.html) and [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#comparison)) and because of the [compatibility](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) mode with other databases (very nice when H2 is not your target database but maybe irrelevant in your context).

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I'll have a look at those.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want something like [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) ([Java bindings](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/)) (a fast flat-file general purpose embeddable database).

Comment: SQLite looks worthwhile too. Thanks Christophe.

Comment: SQLite (and Firebird) are good products but not 100% Java i.e. they can't run in the same Java process. This makes things more complicated.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: good point, a pure-java solution might be more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

You might look at [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx). It has many of the same features as the full version of SQL Server, is free and does not require a separate installation.